# How to run hyperledger fabric REST api from chrome postman

Tags: rest, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Hi All I have setup hyperledger project in my laptop win 7 using docker toolbox. I have peer and membersrvc conatiners running. and also I am able to invoke and query chaincode like `peer chaincode query -l golang -n mycc -c '{"Args": ["query", "b"]}'` and also able to use curl command for REST api from inside docker-machine

> docker-machine ssh default

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{  "jsonrpc": "2.0",  "method": "query",  "params": {"type": 1,"chaincodeID":{"name":"mycc"},"ctorMsg": {"args":["query", "a"]},"secureContext": "jim" }, "id":5}' 172.17.0.3:7050/chaincode`

But problem is not able to access this same REST api "172.17.0.3:7050/chaincode" from browser. 
my docker machine ip is : 192.168.99.100

peer ip : 172.17.0.3

Rest API port : 7050

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried with all the possible IP and port combination for peer but its not accessible from browser. Can you help me what IP and port combination should I use to access REST api from browser. And how I can find the API.

Comment: Did you try with the IP address assigned by DHCP? [which I think is 192.168.99.100 from the screenshot] Also, it would be a good idea to map the ports deliberately using the docker-compose configuration.

Comment: I found the solution for this. yes We need to map the port in docker compose and also we need to map that port to some other port on windows inside virtual machine settings. eg 7050 to 3000. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to this is:

Map default REST port in docker-compose.yml file

```
membersrvc:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc
  command: membersrvc
vp0:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
  ports:
    - "7050:7050"
  environment:
    - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
    - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:2375
    - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
    - CORE_PEER_ID=vp0
    - CORE_PEER_PKI_ECA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
    - CORE_PEER_PKI_TCA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
    - CORE_PEER_PKI_TLSCA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
    - CORE_SECURITY_ENABLED=true
    - CORE_SECURITY_ENROLLID=test_vp0
    - CORE_SECURITY_ENROLLSECRET=MwYpmSRjupbT
  links:
    - membersrvc
  command: sh -c "sleep 5; peer node start --peer-chaincodedev"
```

Now this 7050 port is used under the VM so we should map this port to some other port on windows for example 3000

What you need to understand is that in this setup, with the Docker Toolkit, you actually have two different levels of port mapping. First there is a mapping between the container and the linux VM docker runs in, then there is a mapping between the linux VM and Windows. The mapping specified in your docker-compose.yml file only affects the former. For the latter you need to set that on VirtualBox.

To set the second mapping launch the VirtualBox Manager.
[image]

Select the running VM called “default”. Click on “Settings”. Select “Network”.
[image]

Open the “Advanced” section and click on “Port Forwarding”. Click the “Adds new port forwarding rule” button on the right (the green diamond with a plus sign). Then set Host Port to 3000 and Guest Port to 7050.

[image]

Click Ok. That’s it.

Now, point your browser to https://localhost:3000/network/peers
You should get a page returned from your running peer listing one peer:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the IP address of the "Docker machine" - which in this case is **192.168.99.100** ( **http://192.168.99.100:7050** for REST)

The Swagger doc for the REST API can be found at https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/v0.6/core/rest/rest_api.json